# Change title case (the first letters of all words capitalized) in Vim

Tags: vim, case

There are a lot of solutions around to change the case of the entire word, but what I want is change the case in a way like this:

From "What is the meaning of life? A new proposal" I want: "What is The Meaning of Life? A new Proposal" if that's too hard this: "What Is The Meaning of Life? A New Proposal" would be enough.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: I didn't know a code was necessary. I thought that a keyword shortcut would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly called *title case*; there is a visual mode mapping solution from [the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters#Title_case)

```
function! TwiddleCase(str)
    if a:str ==# toupper(a:str)
        let result = tolower(a:str)
    elseif a:str ==# tolower(a:str)
        let result = substitute(a:str,'\(\<\w\+\>\)', '\u\1', 'g')
    else
        let result = toupper(a:str)
    endif
    return result
endfunction
vnoremap ~ y:call setreg('', TwiddleCase(@"), getregtype(''))<CR>gv""Pgvl
```

#### Alternative

If you want to implement a more robust solution yourself, my [TextTransform plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4005) can help with setting up `x{motion}`, `xx` and `{Visual}x` mappings, so you just need to write the actual transformation function.

**Edit**: Ah well, couldn't stop myself, here is an implementation that is able to handle exceptions:

```
if ! exists('g:TitleCase_ExceptionPattern')
    " Source:
    "   http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html
    let g:TitleCase_ExceptionPattern = '^\%(amid\|a[nst]\?\|and\|are\|but\|by\|down\|for\|from\|i[ns]\|into\|like\|near\|new\|nor\|old\|o[fnr]\|off\|onto\|over\|past\|per\|plus\|than\|the\|to\|up\|upon\|via\|with\)$'
endif
function! TitleCase( text )
    return substitute(a:text, '\(^\<\w\+\>\)\|\<\w\+\>', '\=s:TitleCase(submatch(0), ! empty(submatch(1)))', 'g')
endfunction
function! s:TitleCase( word, isException )
    if ! a:isException && a:word =~# g:TitleCase_ExceptionPattern
        return tolower(a:word)
    endif

    return substitute(a:word, '\w', '\u&', '')
endfunction
call TextTransform#MakeMappings('', '<Leader>s~', 'TitleCase')
```

And here's a variant that cycles through Title Case with exceptions → Title Case all (without exceptions) → lowercase:

```
function! subs#TitleCase#Do( text )
    let l:wordExpr =  '\(^\<\w\+\>\|\<\w\+\>$\)\|\<\w\+\>'
    let l:text = substitute(a:text, l:wordExpr, '\=s:TitleCase(submatch(0), ! empty(submatch(1)))', 'g')
    if l:text ==# a:text
        let l:text = substitute(a:text, l:wordExpr, '\=s:TitleCase(submatch(0), 1)', 'g')
        if l:text ==# a:text
            let l:text = substitute(a:text, l:wordExpr, '\L&', 'g')
        endif
    endif
    return l:text
endfunction
```

Comment: cool. I have no idea how it works. I don't really need to. I add  Vim Tips Wiki's function to my .vimrc. And it worked well. I really would like to have the exceptions option, so I tried your function, but I don't have the option of  "keep pressing ~ until you get the case you want." 
I know that 'vnoremap ~ y:call call TextTransform#MakeMappings('', '<Leader>s~', 'TitleCase', s:lineTypes)' won't suffice. How can I do that?

Comment: Vimballs...  Vimballs everywhere... ;)

Comment: @ziulfer: Thanks. I've added a variant that does cycling, too. Just use `TitleCase` instead of `TwiddleCase` in your `y` mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to capitalize every word.

`:s/\w\+/\u\0/g` appears in the `:substitute` examples. This is viewable after the documentation for `:help s/\\\\`

A less efficient but more intuitive approach is to use `gUl` with the cursor on the first letter of the first word. Then repeat `w.` for all remaining words.